# iPhone & iPad Apps Launch Images

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

**Preamble:** *This is intended to be be a canonical question (and answer) on iOS Apps launch images (aka Default.png).*

**Questions**

1. What is the best way to set the `Default.png`; Manually in the Info.plist or using Xcode (supported in [xcode-4](/questions/tagged/xcode-4) only, I think)
2. Does the iPhone auto-rotate the `Default.png` depending on the device orientation?

   - What effect does the `UIInterfaceOrientation` (Initial interface orientation) key in the Info.plist have?
   - Does `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` and `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` have any effect on displaying the Default.png
3. Can I set different Default.png for the iPad using these file names?:

   - Default-Portrait.png
   - Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png
   - Default-Landscape.png
   - Default-LandscapeLeft.png
   - Default-LandscapeRight.png
4. Are there iPhone equivalents (see 3)
5. Is there any [Apple](http://developer.apple.com) documentation that covers all aspects of "Launch Images"? If so, where?

> **NB:** It seems the usage of launch
>   images changes quite frequently
>   between SDK releases, please indicate
>   in your answers what version you are
>   talking about

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 5) Is there any Apple documentation that covers all aspects of "Launch Images"? If so, where?

There's something [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5):

> **Supply a launch image to improve user experience.**
>
> Avoid using it as an opportunity to
>   provide:
>
> - An “application entry experience,” such as a splash screen
> - An About window
> - Branding elements, unless they are a static part of your application’s
>     first screen

Comment: +1 Great link, I have never seen it before, should be required reading for everyone. I edited your answer with a quote so people can get a gist of it's content.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answers based on latest iPhone iOS

> 1. Manually in the Info.plist or using Xcode (supported in xcode-4 only, I think)

These two methods are equivalent. Xcode merely presents a convenience editor UI for the info.plist. There is no other way to specify the launch image (available to 3rd party developers) than setting it in info.plist.

> 1. Does the iPhone auto-rotate the Default.png depending on the device orientation?

No. but as Springoard does not support upside down, it is unlikely that any portrait apps are launched upside down.

> What effect does the UIInterfaceOrientation (Initial interface orientation) key in the Info.plist have?

None

> Does UISupportedInterfaceOrientations and UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad have any effect on displaying the Default.png

No.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the simplest approach with the easiest maintenance is to simply follow [Apple's conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12) when naming your launch image files. If you **carefully** read and follow those naming conventions, everything else becomes automatic. Automated features include:

- Choosing different launch image files for different device screens.
- Handling the new taller screen found on current iPhone 5/5S & iPod touch.
- Handling Retina screens.
- Handling device orientation (Portrait vs Landscape) on iPad. (handhelds have only Portrait)
- Displaying thumbnails in Xcode 4

If you:

- Create image files with the correct resolution (carefully read the doc, as resolutions are not what you might expect)
- Follow the naming rules [documented by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)
- Place the files at the top level of your app bundle†

…then:

- Thumbnails of the images will automatically appear within project settings of Xcode 4.
- Your launch images will automatically be used on devices as well as the *iOS Simulator*.

By following the naming conventions, you need **not**:

- Select images manually in the Xcode project settings
- Edit any info-plist

The naming conventions work at least in iOS 5, 6, and 7. I believe they also work in earlier versions as well.

---

†Image files should *not* be nested in any physical folder. After adding them to Xcode, you may group them into a virtual folder within Xcode's project listing to avoid visual clutter.

---

Tip: To verify which image is being used, alter the image itself to display the file name as part of the image. Make a backup of your images first, of course.

Comment: bro could you please help me to check out my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955856/different-launch-screen-image-or-background-image-sizes-for-ios-devices ?