# Different Launch Screen Image or Background Image Sizes for iOS devices

Tags: swift3, photoshop, retina-display, image-size, launch-screen

I read some of those website links that explain about exporting different image sizes for iOS device. But I don't really understand of those explaining. (May be I am not good at in English language.)
[image]

I found these dimension for launch screen. Please let me clarify my understanding to you guys.
So, when I create an image, I must create a larger size(@3x) firstly and should export that image into smaller sizes (@2x, @1x). Am I right? 
For example,  I create 1242x2208px (3x) image and scale to 2x,3x and save. 

[image]

*My questions are that;* 
1) I draw images in Photoshop CS6.For any size of images, the **Resolution** is still 75px. isn't it? 
So, for 1242x2208px(3x) size , the resolution is 75px and then I decrease the size. The image will small and does it get blurry appearance? 
2) Does image elements (**heart image** in my example image)need to make to be large in smaller device(1x) to get the clear looks?  **Or**
3) If we don't need to modify image elements or may be some texts of font size to be large or small, can we get the high resolution of image appearance in 1x? I'm afraid that if we scale to smaller(1x), it would be blur and not good in looks because we are still in 75 resolutions. 
4) Does it need to make to fit the image elements to image size? 
I found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOnczJSsMqk . In this video, he crops the white space and export into @1x, @2x and @3x. So, the size of @3x is not the image size from Apple official Guideline website. I don't know clearly this. 
5) If we type the *text (font size-90pt) in @3x* image, then it will automatically changes to *60pt in @1x* image. right? 
 
But in this link https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/retina-design-in-photoshop/#font-size , he wrote that

> a text box with the font set to 16 pixels. But @2x this is 32 pixels,
>   and @3x it’s 48 pixels!
>   Not ideal, is it, having to constantly multiply by two or three? I
>   don’t know about you, but I could do without the constant math. **When I
>   design, I want to know that 16 pixels is 16 pixels!**

So, the text should be *16 px* in any size of image 1x,2x or 3x or not?

6) These image sizes are for launch screen, isn't it? But, if I create an image for background of Login screen, then is it the same concept and save as these sizes of image ?

7) Above image size dimension is correct or not? But, in this https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/ website, the sizes are a little bit different.

Now, I'm trying to create a design for login background image. So, I was finding the sizes before I draw. But, after reading many articles of image sizes in Retina device, I've confused and got many questions in my mind. 
That's why I write down my questions like this and I would like to say sorry that my question is long and make you feel not easy to understand. 
Sorry again for my poor English. 
I hope anyone would help me to answer all my questions in steps.Thanks for reading till the end. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are asking way to much here.  First off, you do not work in pixels. You work in points.  These are 2 different units of measurements.  On a 1x scale 1 point = 1x1 pixel, on a 2x scale 1 point = 2x2 pixel, and on a 3x scale, 1 point = 3x3 pixels.

Now when it comes to how to scale, people claim that you start big and you got small for best quality.  This is simply not true.  It all depends on the actual image as to how it will scale. So your goal is to find what works best for the image. I would recommend starting off from big to small, but if it doesn't work out as nice as you like, go small to big, then try a different scaling method.
I personally do not rely 100% on automation,  I like to tweak all 3 sizes manually until the images are perfect, which makes sprite-kit really tough to work with in this department because I have to design my graphics in a way that counter act the hardware scaling.  Bottom line is at the end of the day, do what is best for your app within your budget constraints.

Now when it comes to font sizes, again you are working in points, not pixels.  Whoever told you that you need to multiply has no understanding of how retina display works.  So when you do 16pt font, the system will automatically pick 32pt and 48pt. (But if you read it it will still say 16pt)

Try not to over think this matter, it is really simple to understand.  The entire point of retina display is to provide a sharper image while maintaining the same experience, and it does this by offering more granularity in the way pixels are displayed. Each individual pixel is very very tiny, which makes it hard to see with your eyes. Instead they are companions to other pixels, so that when your eyes put the 2 pixels together, you get a better looking image that could not be produced by using a single colored pixel.  When you work on your apps, you want to keep this in mind.  This is why it stinks for new people to get into development.  Everybody should start with the iphone 2g, then adapt their app to iphone 4.  They will get a clear understanding of what retina is built for.

Comment: @KnightofDragon, thanks for explaining me in details bro. I might be over thinking to my project image.  thanks bro. :) Have a good day for you bro.