# Launch Screen Image size in iOS

Tags: swift3, splash-screen, retina-display, launch-screen

I found image sizes are not the same in these websites.
1) https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/    
**and**

2) https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes

Nowadays, apple does not use "Splash" screen and they use "launch" screen instead of this. 
So, for background image of Login screen, which site should I refer to?
 
 Could anyone help me please?

Comment: follow apple link as they have standard size for Launch Screen.

Comment: Bro @Shabirjan , Do I need to create both Portrait and Landscape Images? In github link, they said that we don't need to draw all images. Btw bro, could you look at my question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955856/different-launch-screen-image-or-background-image-sizes-for-ios-devices ?

Comment: If your app supports both Portrait and Landscape than yeah